# Is it safe to install spyder multiple times with conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, multiple-versions

Specifically I'm thinking about conflicting preferences/config/autosave files, since spyder (currently installed to my default `base` cond env) creates a .spyder-py3 directory in my userprofile as well as many other things.

Are there any special considerations I should take into account before installing a second instance in another conda env. I want to install a newer version of spyder that conflicts with some files in my monolithic base environ.

Comment: Personally, I would only ever install infrastructure, such as Spyder, once on a system, and provide a dedicated environment (not **base**) for it. [Spyder supports loading other Conda environments as kernels](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#working-with-other-environments-and-python-installations).

Comment: @merv yeah that's broadly my plan, although it kind of defeats one of the 2 reasons to use anaconda which is that its base environ comes with a load of common packages installed by default. This was the main selling point when I was a beginner. (The other reason is conda package management)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no problem on installing Spyder in as many environments as you want. The only thing to take into account is that all installed Spyder's read their configuration from the same directory (i.e. the `spyder-py3` directory you mentioned above), and that could give you problems when running different versions.

Comment: However, in Spyder **5.1.2** we added a command line option called `--conf-dir` to point to a specific directory to read and write Spyder's configuration. That will avoid that issue.